# Переадресация писем на node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, email

Требуется сделать простой редирект писем на node.js. К сожалению, абсолютно не знаком с smtp и вообще с тем как устроена почта.

Сейчас запущен http (https) -сервер на ноде. На его адрес нужно отравлять письма, они должны редиректиться на mail.ru. Объясните в какую сторону копать, можно просто словами. Спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Привяжите домен к Яндексу (https://pdd.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=6213) и не мучайтесь.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но все ящики на mail.ru и не хочется открывать два сайта, что бы проверять почту. А привязывать сперва к яндексу, а потом яндекс привязывать к мейлу — какой-то изврат

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz, вы можете привязать домен к Яндекс.Почте и сделать тем перенаправление писем на любые ваши ящики Mail.Ru. Или настроить сбор почты с Яндекса в настройках Mail.Ru. Или использовать [Mail.Ru для бизнеса](https://biz.mail.ru/). Или начать в 2017 использовать почтовые клиенты.

Comment: @terron про переадресацию с яндекса на меил я написал выше. На счет почтовых клиентов — я их использую, но мне важна возможность просто открыть веб-страницу, а не скачивать почтовый клиент и настраивать его, в случае если не будет собственного устройства под рукой. В общем, это к сути вопроса всё это не относится